# Sencha Charts Extending Columns outside of the view port

Tags: extjs, sencha-charts

I'm working on getting familiar with Sencha charts. I'd like to know if there is any way that I can extend a column outside of the view port. For example I have data for which I have the min, first quartile, third quartile, and max for and I make a stacked chart out of these. However the max contains several outliers that probably won't be relevant to the user. What I want to do is end the view after the third quartile somewhere. Is there a simple and easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: how about taking outliers out of the data set?

Comment: That would be nice to do but not what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to work out the algorithm to get the percentage of records that go beyond your third quartile. That shouldn't be too hard.

Then create a function that set's the *chart's* width to a size which is equal to:

`[viewport width] * (1 + [the percentage])`

You can use the chart's `setWidth` method for this.

You can call this function in the chart's `beforerefresh` event (it should fire after the chart store data is loaded but before it is rendered on the chart) and also in the viewport's resize event.